"3 DOORS down from me." VS "3 BLOCKS down from me."
When giving directions, I sometimes hear the word "blocks" and sometimes "doors" being used. For example:

My neighbour was 3 DOORS down from me.


My neighbour was 3 BLOCKS down from me.

As a non-native speaker, it meant the same to me in meaning for quite some time, and I thought that there would be 2 houses/houses of flats/buildings between the speaker and his neighour.
However, after I have seen pictures of blocks (I have attached one here), I found out that a block is actually a very big piece of land than and might include more than one building/house/house of flats. So I am not sure if "3 blocks down" would be the same as "3 doors down".
For example, if someone says my friend lives 4 blocks away, then the friend might actually be living 16 doors away (1 block translating to 4 seperate buildings, each of which can contain one or multiple flats).
So, is my thinking right and if yes should we use "doors" rather than "blocks" to be more precise?
 "blocks"

"Three blocks down" is more likely to be used in an urban environment where people live in blocks of flats/apartments, and "three doors away" in a suburban or village street of individual houses with their own front doors.

In American English, a block is defined by the cross-streets. A block extends from one cross-street to the next.  There are five blocks between 10th Street and 15th Street.

I don't normally use it myself, but I'm guessing some people say 3 doors [down / up the road because in a country like the UK we have a lot of semi-detached houses. If yours and the neighbours houses are semis, both 2 and 3 doors down definitely mean the next but one house, which is often a useful guide to proximity.

In the US, cities have blocks, and so do some small towns.  Wherever there is a grid pattern of streets, with cross-streets, you can use the word "block" and each block has a different number.  For example, you can say "I live on the 600 block of Elm Avenue".  All the houses in that block will be in the 600 range. 624 Elm Avenue. The next block up is the 700 block.

@KateBunting, so in urban environment, if someone says "My friend lives in 3 blocks away", does it mean "The friend lives in 3 buildings away, (not in the sense a block being a piece of land where more than one blocks-of-flats could have been built?

@Yunus Always "lives three blocks away", never "lives in three blocks away".

@TimR, Exactly what I wanted to find out. Thanks. If someone says "I live on the 600 block", he is not giving the full number of flat he is in. Then we should ask, "Ok you live in the 600 block, but there are 3 buildings on that block, so which one is your home?"

@stangdon, thanks, just a typo. I wanted to correct it but I can not anymore (5 minute limit on editing comments)

It is often the case that even large apartment complexes will be given a single street address, e.g.  714 Maple Avenue.  They might take up half a block or the entire block.  So you sometimes will see 714 Maple Avenue, Building 2, Apt 3C.   That would be the third apartment on the third floor of building 2.   The alpha in "3C" implies there's a 3A and a 3B but not necessarily a 3D.

Especially in small towns house numbering on blocks can be arbitrary.  You might live at 609 Elm St, and be the first house on the block, with no houses numbered 601-608.  It can be the result of a lot plan that was drawn up, and then a section of the street that was formerly going to be residential was reallocated to hold a school, and the lots numbered 601-608 are removed, leaving the first house on the street 609.

FYI, in New York City, there is an understanding there are roughly 20 blocks in a mile, so each block of buildings, between street intersections, is about  260 ft (~80 m). See https://streeteasy.com/blog/how-many-nyc-blocks-are-in-one-mile/ for more info.

Yunus, as I live in a suburban street in England I don't know all the details of how Americans speak of 'blocks' - which is why I made a comment and not an answer.

In Philadelphia, it's about double the NYC ratio.  10 blocks to a mile.

It's not quite correct to describe blocks as more or less "precise" than doors; they are simply different kinds of measurements.  That is to say, you shouldn't think of a block as a meter and door as centimeter.  These are not in any way standardized units.
In this context, block means essentially the space between two parallel (roughly speaking) streets.  In a city with a very strict grid street plan, you might be able to predict the length of a block.  In Manhattan, for example, there are areas with a consistent grid pattern, where streets running east-west are spaced 264ft, or 80m apart, and north-south streets are spaced 900ft, or 274m apart.  So, if we knew you were walking "uptown" (from south to north), and you said, "it's five blocks away", we'd know the distance was about 1/4 of a mile, and that it would take about five minutes to walk.
But even in the grid-like parts of Manhattan, the buildings within a block can be very different sizes.  So if you were to say, "it's five doors down," we would not really be able to assume what the distance might be.  There are sections of cities where buildings are essentially the same size, and there are the same number on each block, but I feel quite safe in assuming that if we're talking about cities generally, these uniform building sizes are exceptional, rather than customary.  In other words, there blocks, like the one in the OP's picture, where there are consistently four buildings on each block, and if your audience knew you were talking about that area, "three doors down" would give a precise measurement.  But you cannot say that "doors" is generally more precise than "blocks".
So is the reverse true; should we use "blocks" to be precise?  No, because outside of very specific contexts, like the strictly grid sections of Manhattan, block might mean something different, or might mean something very unspecific.
In Chicago, for instance, the grid has different measurements, 330 by 660 feet (100 m × 200 m).  If I don't know what city you're talking about, or if I don't even know that there are different standards, I won't be able to figure out the correct distance.
And, on top of the different standards, there's the fact that very standardized grid patterns are the exception, not the rule, virtually everywhere.  Boston's downtown is somewhat tree-shaped, so the northern side of a block might be four times shorter than the southern side:


